# What kendo datasource schema-model are all about?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui-grid

I tried to explore [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/local-data-binding) on dojo
And then, I just noticed these lines of code:

```
      dataSource: {
            data: products,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                       fields: {
                            ProductName: { type: "string" },
                            UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                            Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                        }
                     }
                 },
```

I tried to delete the whole `schema` thing and it works just fine. It doesn't affect the columns and fields and even the loading performance.

Now I wonder the purpose of that thing. I do some quick research, and I found nothing specific.

Comment: `fields` and `model` can have non-default configuration, and many other settings. Even in your case deleting `schema` yields to different result, it's just not obvious. Note, type "boolean" and check what is the default type for the field.

Comment: In their example, i added a boolean field. and I can still change it's format to check field using template like `{ field: "Discontinued", template: '<input type="checkbox" #= Discontinued ? "checked=checked" : "" # disabled="disabled" ></input>' }`. it just doesn't make sense to me if why do we need to add that '`schema` codes' if you can achieve the same thing without it.